# Is there a way to make a URL for my router's IP (192.168.0.1)

Tags: networking, router

Is there a way to set a URL to go to 192.168.0.1? My cPanel refuses to let me do it:

[image]

---

Using HTML redirect code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=192.168.0.1">
```

Doesn't work either:

[image]

My router is a [D-Link DIR-655 Firmware v2](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-655-wireless-n-gigabit-router)

I don't want to enable any remote management stuff, I want it to be a requirement to be logged into my home network to work on the router's admin panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An address can be used in place of the hostname in a URL.

```
http://192.168.0.1/
```